# PC games lag, but nothing else does

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, lag

Recently about 2 weeks ago my PC shut down and refused to come back on due to a system32 config error. I fixed this by reinstalling the operating system through a flash drive. I got a good connection running and all that good stuff, but I have noticed that all my games, regardless of their resource usage, always lag to the point it's unplayable almost. This only occurs with games, not with my browser, videos, or anything else. This didn't happen before I reinstalled my operating system, the games would run fine.

I can confirm the issue isn't with my network, since everything on my browser works fine with the internet I have, and so does every other device connected to my network.

I think it may be due to the operating system because I reinstalled it, but im not sure what it is about the operating system.

My operating system is windows 10, and I got the things on the flash drive to reinstall it from [Microsoft themselves.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

If anyone has questions about anything feel free to ask, this is a very annoying issue for me considering I primarily use this PC for gaming. :/

Comment: Probably it needs drivers that were present in the original installation and you didn't install now. I'm assuming that to be the case because you only mentioned the OS installation itself.

Comment: I didn't install any drivers after reinstalling it except for one that is used by an external thing I use.

I don't remember having any particular drivers I downloaded for games even before the OS reinstall but I've had it for a long time so I may have forgotten. I may have to look into it.

Comment: ChanganAuto Ok so naturally my first thought was: "Maybe it's the graphics driver or something" so I went and checked for updates to that driver, apparently when I installed the OS it put the driver as a windows default one instead of a Radeon one (the one I've been using), so I installed the Radeon one, and now the games work perfectly fine L thankyou so much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Changan has said, probably you need graphics drivers. GPU-Z may help you in identifying what GPU you have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).